# Can not inspect my debug build in Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, safari, testflight

I executed the next steps:

1) Changed my app scheme **to debug** in **Archive mode**.

2) I created an archive.

3) I uploaded it to the iTunes connect.

4) I made needed build available for testing and invited beta testers.

5) I downloaded an app from the Testflight app with beta tester's credentials.

6) I activated Settings/Safari/Advanced/Web Inspector mode on the device and Develop mode in Safari on my Mac.

7) So now I'm running my debug build which was downloaded from the Testflight and **I can not inspect the Webview of my app within the Safari Develop mode**. It says "No inspectable applications".

I don't understand what's the problem. Does Testflight restrict debug mode for the builds?

Could somebody help me with it?

Comment: It's entirely possible. The ability to debug webviews is probably tied to the app being signed with a development certificate (and testflight builds aren't). But why go to such length if you have the source ? Why not just debug a build you launch from Xcode ?

Comment: @deadbeef I'm asking for our QA department. I can just debug a build I launch from Xcode but our testers not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found out what was the problem.

For inspecting your app within Safari Develop mode your build should be signed with **iOS Development Certificate**. But when you are uploading your app to TestFlight - Xcode automatically resign it with **iOS Distribution Certificate**. With this type of Certificate, you can not inspect Webview of your application in Safari.

Comment: Solved it for me man, i guess they disable it for production, else i could see your assets. Thanks